# Salvar tags do select2 via post para o php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-select2

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso enviar um `POST` com as `tags` selecionadas no `select2` (versão 4). Meu código funciona perfeitamente, mas não posso enviar o resultado das **tags** selecionadas para o servidor `php`, logo nenhuma delas fica salva.

Os dados são *remotos*, o que dificultou mais ainda as minhas tentativas.
O objetivo seria passar os dados via `POST` ao `php` que salvaria os mesmos separando os valores por `,` Ex: `valor1, valor dois, etc`

Atualmente uso o `x-editable` com `php` para salvar os dados, porem o meu `select2` usado atualmente obtêm os dados dinamicamente e não consegui integrar os dois.

**JSON DATA**

```
{ "items": [{"text":"Meu Nome","id":"xyz05410"}]}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" multiple="multiple"
style="width: 100%" class="form-control select2"></select>
```

**JS**

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax2").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "get_data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        term: params.term // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  //tags: true,
  theme: "bootstrap",
  tokenSeparators: [","],
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'Insert tags',

  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

> Existem alguma forma de salvas as tags selecionada do `select2`([v4](https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/master/dist/js)) no php?

Comment: Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, deixe nos comentários, referencias do gênero, para que possam ajudar a mim e a quem procura informações relevantes.

Answer (score -2):

Amigo depois de tanto tempo, talvez não necessite mais, mesmo assim vou postar.
Estava com o mesmo problema, resolvi apenas acrescentado [] no nome do select.